# Polymer data binding an object with properties with space in the name

Tags: javascript, polymer

I'm trying to display a value in an object, but I don't know the right syntax to do so.

Given a property of type Object like `{"name": "bob", "pets name": "fido"}`

How can I display the pets name fido?

I've tried

`<div>[[myObject["pets name"]]]</div>`

and `<div>[[myObject]]["pets name]</div>`

and `<div>[[myObject.pets name]]</div>`

and `<div>[[myObject."pets name"]]</div>`

Answer (score 1):

I made a workaround to just use a computed binding, but the problem is that sometimes the object is empty, and I only want to display something when it has data.

```
<div>[[_getPetName(myObj)]]</div>
```

and

```
...
properties:{
myObj:{ type: Object, value: {"name":"bob", "pet name":"fido"} }
},
_getPetName: function(myObj){
return myObj['pet name'];
}
```

Comment: ```_getPetName: function(myObj){
if(myObj['pet name'] !== undefined)
   return myObj['pet name'];
else return ""
}```

Comment: Thanks Varad  - Yeah, that's what I ended up doing. Is there a better way to handle this? The reason is that I'd like to hide the paper-card that shows this information until the object is full. There's an input box that asks for "Name" - if I give it "bob" I'd like "fido" to show up. Sometimes the card appears, but the _getPetName function fires BEFORE the object is full, so I get an empty card.

Comment: My solution for now, is instead of using <div>[[_getPetName(myObj)]]</div> I just leave the div empty and give it an ID, like <div id="petnametext">, and 
 I made a boolean called wasFound, then the _getPetName function is  if(this.wasFound) { this.$.petnametext.textContent = myObj['pet name']}
I feel dirty, it's awful code.

Comment: Check [ conditional templates ] (https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/templates#dom-if)